# Determining Lie algebra: are my thoughts correct?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $UT_1(n, \mathbb R)$ denote the set of all upper triangular real matrices with diagonal equal to $1$. This is a Lie group. I am trying to determine its Lie algebra.

> Please can you tell me if my thoughts are correct?

If $A=A(t)$ is a differentiable curve $A: (-1,1)\to UT_1(n, \mathbb R)$ with $A(0) = I$ then its diagonal is constant and since we take the derivative termwise, $A'$ has a zero diagonal.

The remaining upper triangle consists of any elements. I think this because the Lie algebra of the general linear group is all matrices. Now we can take the subgroup of triangular matrices (that's the set of *invertible* triangular matrices) and by the same reasoning its Lie algebra should be *all* triangular matrices.

Hence,

$$ \mathfrak{ut}_1 = \{ A \in M_n(\mathbb R) \mid A \text{ is upper triangular with zero diagonal }\}$$

Comment: You have correctly identified the Lie algebra.  It's a little loose with details though.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Why the down vote?